# Cannot See Urdu Font Correctly on Android

Tags: android, fonts, arabic, urdu

I am developing an app that includes Urdu text. I downloaded the "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq" font from http://jameel-noori-nastaleeq-urdu-fonts.software.informer.com/1.0/. On some mobiles, it shows up just fine but on most of the mobiles it looks jumbled up. I have tried different fonts from different sites but the problem persists. I haven't been able to figure out whether it is Android Version, mobile device or some other parameter that has the issue. Need help in this regard. I am attaching both correctly displayed and jumbled up snapshots. Thanks

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

Comment: to do find solution of this Question?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try the following fonts as well.

- Alvi Nastaleeq
- Pak Nastaleeq
- Fajer Noori Nastaleeq
- Urdu naskh asiatype

You can download from here http://www.urdujahan.com/font.html

If you still face the similar issue the try using  Faiz Lahori Nastaliq (http://www.axissoftmedia.com ) font which apparently has full Unicode support .